# How to restrict what shows up in a table (i.e. when using 2 separate tables)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm creating a financial area on my site, using Ruby on Rails, Twitter Bootstrap. I have to use two different tables, one for Winnings, other for Expenses.

The thing is, I use the same model for these two types of entries. I created an attribute (type) to specify if each entry is a winning or expense. What I want to know is how I can restrict each type to it's proper table. I need only to show wins in one and only expenses on the other.

---

Edit: I tried this:

In my controller:

```
def index

 @winning = Finance.where(type: 'Arrecadação')
 @expense = Finance.where(type: 'Despesa')

end
```

And then on my view, I'm not sure how to restrict it, so:

```
  <% if finances.expense %>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-sort="string">Tipo</th>
        <th data-sort="int-small">Valor</th>
        <th data-sort="string">Descrição</th>
        <th>Data</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% @finances.each do |finance| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= finance.type %></td>
          <td><%= finance.value %></td>
          <td><%= finance.info %></td>
          <td><%=h finance.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
```

I'm new to coding so I don't really know how to use references in controllers and such things.

Comment: Add some code that you have tried to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@winnings = MyFinancialModel.where(type: 'win')
@expenses = MyFinancialModel.where(type: 'expense')
```

See [the Active Record Querying reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Okay, I got it! Your code helped me a lot. I just changed "<% (at)finances.each do |finance| %>" for "<% (at)winning.each do |finance| %>". I should've got this earlier. Thanks a bunch"